# What method to use in "ATM" based program

Tags: python, pseudocode

I've started with a assignment for a ATM code, I'm supposed to use text file in some way or another. so far I've got this:

```
print("Hello, and welcome to the ATM machine!\n")

a_pin = {1111, 2222, 3333, 4444}

def process():
    pin = int(input("\nplease enter below your 4-digit pin number: "))
    if pin in a_pin:
        if pin == (1111):
            f = open("a.txt", "r")
        elif pin == (2222):
            f = open("b.txt", "r")
        elif pin == (3333):
            f = open("c.txt", "r")
        elif pin == (4444):
            f = open("d.txt", "r")
        print(
    """
        MENU:
        1: view your current balance
        2: make a withdraw
        3: make a deposit
        4: exit

     """)

        option = input("\nwhat would you like to do? ")

        if option == "1":
            print(f.read())
        elif option == "2":
            y = str(input("\nHow much would you like you like to withdraw? "))
            f.write(y)
            print("Excellent, your transaction is complete!")
        elif option == "3":
            z = str(input("\nHow much would you like to deposit? "))
            f.write(z)
            print("Excellent, your transaction is complete!")
        elif option == "4":
            input("Please press the enter key to exit.")



    else:
        print("\nthat was a wrong pin number!")
        x = input("\nwould you like to try again? '(y/n)' ")
        if x == "y":
            process()
        else:
            input("\npress the enter key to exit.")

process()
```

The code works as of now, but I want to save some time by asking how to most effectively overwrite content on the text files when withdrawing/depositing. 
I was thinking of pickled files... but will be very happy for any suggestions, since normal commands like write dont really work for this task, if i want to display the new ammount to user after a withdraw/deposit.
Many thanks!

Comment: Please fix your indentations.

Comment: Does each file keeps a log of transactions or just keeps the current balance?

Comment: Im aiming to only keep the most updated balance, transfer log is not required so i will not do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key point is to consider the necessary "mode" to open the file so that it can be not only be read `(r)` but also modified `(r+)`:

```
if pin == (1111):
        f = open("a.txt", "r+")
    elif pin == (2222):
        f = open("b.txt", "r+")
    elif pin == (3333):
        f = open("c.txt", "r+")
    elif pin == (4444):
        f = open("d.txt", "r+")
```

Then store the current balance in the file, and update it after each transaction.

```
# read current balance from file and save its value
bal = float(f.read().strip('\n'))  # or replace float() with int()

# reset file pointer to beginning of file before updating contents
f.seek(0)

if option == '1':
    print(f.read()) # or simply, print(bal)
elif option == '2':
    y = str(input("\nHow much would you like you like to withdraw? "))
    bal -= int(y)            # calculate new balance
    f.write(str(bal)+'\n')   # write new balance to file as a string
    print("Excellent, your transaction is complete!")
elif option == '3':
    z = str(input("\nHow much would you like to deposit? "))
    bal += int(z)
    f.write(str(bal)+'\n')
    print("Excellent, your transaction is complete!")
```

Comment: exactly what i was looking for! Thank you very much, you helped me a ton :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are only keeping the most updated balance, try to open the text file in w+ mode, read the entire line and keep the value in your program, modify it however you want and finally write the end value and add an end of line. If should renew the value each time you run the program.